# Matplotlib Subplot Labels Disappear

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I want to prepare some hexbin plots from Pandas. My initial code is:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

df2.plot(kind='hexbin', x='var1', y='var2', C='var3', reduce_C_function=np.median,  gridsize=25,vmin=0, vmax=40,ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlim([-5,2])
ax1.set_ylim([0,7])
```

However when I change this to:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
```

And plot create four subplots similar to the first example it turns off the xlabels and xticklabels.

What code to I need to switch them back on? And is this something I can do as a defaults?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this problem and couldn't. Can you create some example code that breaks the xlabels and xticklabels? And, if possible, post an image of the results?